Start VLC via SSH and close connection
I want to start vlc playing a video via an SSH connection to and immediately close the SSH connection after vlc has started playing. No matter what I try (using screen, using an &, using nohup) vlc will either stop completely, or the video will stop but the audio continues.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

To clarify, you're trying to tell the SSH server machine to start playing a video on its own monitor, then close the tunnel and leave the server to play the video unattended, correct? Also, what OS is the server machine running?

Consider the options given in this answer to a similar question: https://serverfault.com/a/36436/481587

Yes, that is correct, re: "To clarify, you're trying to tell the SSH server machine to start playing a video on its own monitor, then close the tunnel and leave the server to play the video unattended, correct?"
The final OS is Raspbian, but my work session is Ubuntu (both Debian and same result on both)

I had already tried both nohup and &. Both did not work - i.e., one the tunnel closed, the video stopped (although interestingly, on one of the options left the audio still playing).
